# Getting Currency from QuickBooks Online

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to sync invoice from quickbooks to my app.
I need currency used by the customer or the invoice currency?

Is there any API to get Currency from Quickbooks Online.
I'm using PHP devkit(IPP).

Answer (score 3):

With QBO IDS V2 there is no API to get currency. With IDS V3, currency is exposed.

Comment: Worth noting that as of Feb 14, 2013, IDS v3 has not been released.